# How to remove some portion of an image

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to build a component, where it takes images and the first image will be shown while remaining images will be shown in a half circle.

Here I am trying to clip the image portion from second image by adding a class which is not working. I need to get the images as shown in the attached image below.

**Images.js**

```
const Images = ({ images = [] }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {images?.map((image, index) => {
        const isFirst = index === 0;
        return (
          <img
            src={image.url}
            alt={image.title}
            key={image.title}
            className={isFirst ? "" : "semi-circle"}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Images;
```

**style.css**

```
img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.semi-circle {
  clip: rect(0px, 25px, 25px, 0px);
}
```

What am I doing wrong here.

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-feynman-is87r)

See the image that illustrates what I'm trying to achieve:

[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXs5X.jpg)

Comment: `which is not working`, what is not working? the images are shown but your `semi-circle` class does get added?

Comment: @Phani i have added one rough image, which I wanted to have the output

Comment: @Phani first image will be shown entirely rest images will be a more than half circle portion will be shown between having spaces can you check the attached image => this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `clip-path: path()` to create custom shapes. This is now supported in modern browsers.

```css
.semi-circle {
    clip-path: path('m27.215 9.6962c70.511-13.195 81.235 89.479 4.948 82.882 16.494-5.773 43.709-54.43-4.948-82.882z');
}
```

[Updated Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-beaver-wxi9c?file=/src/styles.css:138-272)

[Clip-path Caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_clip-path_path)

Comment: This works, one doubt if i want to increase more width of the .semi-circle like now it has more spacing, how can i reduce it. Also how did you get this path any online tool for the same ?

Comment: How can i reduce the spacing between the images

Comment: You need to create the path by making use of any vector graphic tools (eg. Illustrator) to create a perfect path for your requirement. Also you can use negative margin to move the elements.

Comment: Okay in that case if we apply margin-left then when I tried https://codesandbox.io/s/late-platform-m19yq for the second image it should be -40px for the third image it should be -60px, so how can I handle this because since its dynamic

Comment: You can achieve this by adding negative margin for sibling semi-circles. Sandbox has been updated for your requirement.

[Updated sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-beaver-wxi9c?file=/src/styles.css)